# WCF service to send large binaries to server

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to upload large (100 meg max) binairies to server using WCF. I followed instructions from this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/fileuploadsilverlightwcf07142009104020AM/fileuploadsilverlightwcf.aspx

it workds for anything less than 50K. going above that I get 415 errors. any idea?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the __maxbuffersize__, try increasing them.

Comment: Isn't it possible to pass a Stream object to the service to suck instead ? That is much more suitable for passing large files.

Comment: Thanks everyone. it was the binding problem. thanks for your help. and yes, I'm now using the stream....

Comment: there was a collection of suggestions in the form of comments and no one "correct" answere. please read everything before commenting...

Answer (score 1):

is there a max POST size limit on your server?

Comment: I have the max on the binding set to a big number:
       <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="MyWindowsAuthenticationBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" maxBufferSize="2000000">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000"/>
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
             </security>
          </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>

is it the same thing or there is some other max I have to set as well?

Comment: I'm not sure about IIS but when I've trun web services on Tomcat I've hit problems because the server has a maximum amount that can be submitted in an HTTP POST request.  Might be worth checking IIS's settings to see if there is a similar setting there.

Googling for IIS max post size, seems to turn up a bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try setting maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferSize to int.MAX and upping the value of maxItemsInObjectGraph.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c85f3ed2-0b55-4375-af79-5926b6cc527c

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your binding configuration:

```
<binding name="MyWindowsAuthenticationBinding" closeTimeout="05:00:00" openTimeout="05:00:00" receiveTimeout="05:00:00" sendTimeout="05:00:00" maxBufferSize="2000000000" maxBufferPoolSize="2000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000000" maxArrayLength="2000000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000000" />
```